Can a right-multiplying matrix be transformed into a left-multiplying matrix?
Let $A, P, X$ be square real matrices such that $$AP = X.$$  Under what conditions does a matrix $Q$ exist such that $$QA = X$$ and how do I find it?

It is traditional to add more context than this (have you tried anything? where did the problem arise? what tools do you know? etc.).  Note that the condition $QA = X$ implies that the null space of $A$ is contained in the null space of $X$.  Can you show this condition to be sufficient for the existence of such $Q$?  (The case when $A$ is invertible has been handled in an answer.) Note that in general there will be no uniqueness (e.g. if $A = 0$ then $X = 0$ and any $Q$ will do), and if this condition is indeed enough, it may not matter what $P$ is, or even if there is any such $P$.

If we assume for the moment that $A$ is invertible, then you're hoping to find a $Q$ with $$
AP = QA.
$$
That can be rewritten as
$$
APA^{-1} = Q
$$
which (in fancy language) says that $P$ and $Q$ are in the same conjugacy class.
One fact about conjugate matrices: they have the same eigenvalues. But "same eigenvalues" alone is not enough to ensure conjugacy -- consider
$$
P = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1},  Q = \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1}.
$$
Both of these have $1$ as an eigenvalue twice, but they are not conjugate. (Reason: if you transform to Jordan normal form, conjugate matrices end up the same. But both $P$ and $Q$ are already in JNF, so ... they're not conjugate).
Everything I've just said depended on $A$ being invertible. If $A$ is not invertible,  then things are more subtle. For instance,  Using the matrix
$P$ above, and $A$ being the $0$ matrix, we actually have $AP = QA$ where $Q$ is the other matrix shown above.
So a lot also depends on the matrix $A$. Broadly speaking, the more degenerate it is (i.e., the lower its rank), the easier it is to find $Q$ (if one exists).

Being in the same conjugacy class may be necessary, but certainly isn't sufficient, as evidenced by the fact that we can have $AP \neq PA$.  What's sufficient is, if $A$ is invertible, to set $Q := APA^{-1}$. Is that correct?

Sure. So that takes care of the "A is invertible" case. Unfortunately, I suspect that it's the easy one. :(
